# Knowledge required for making a simple CLI C++ program that finds lyric for a song and displays it to the user

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner to C++ and I want to make a program that finds lyrics for songs entered by the user and displays it to the screen.

What are the things I should know about to build this program?

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning to do this the GUI way?

Comment: I'm afraid these kind of questions are offtopic for this site.

Comment: You should *design* the program.  Search the internet for "c++ how to search internet Api" or find a lyric database and search the site for information on how to access it.

Comment: nope, Only using command line interface

Comment: I also recommend studying database theory and data structures.

Comment: Are you prompting the User or do you want the User to pass song as parameter to your program?

Comment: i want the user to pass the name of the song as a parameter

Comment: And is it possible to use musixmatch API?

Answer (score 0):

What you need essentially is to revisit your C++ tutorials and relearn. Try to take first rung before stepping midway on a ladder.

That been said, you will need - not arranged in any particular order:

1. Find a lyrics provider and read their API documentation ( or have the lyrics in a file or db!)
2. Learn how to parse XML or JSON or text
3. Learn how to retrieve data over a network or from file or db
4. Learn how to construct searches

If you are looking for a code snippet then I am afraid you are on the wrong site. You should look at Github for that as that is too bulky for a Q&A site.

Good luck!